# Why does the 'which' command in Terminal give no output in 20.04?

Tags: gnome-terminal

In Ubuntu 18.04 I could use the 'which' command like this:

```
$ which python
```

To get information on where a certain script etc. was located. But on Ubuntu 20.04 it does not give any output:

```
henrik@henrik-thinkpad-20-04:~$ which python
henrik@henrik-thinkpad-20-04:~$ which
henrik@henrik-thinkpad-20-04:~$
```

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there is no `python` command installed by default in the system.

Historically `python` was used for Python version 2.x. Since Python 2 is EOL, there is no longer a  command called `python` to call the Python 2 interpreter.

You can install the `python-is-pyhon3` package to have a shortcut `python` calling the Python 3 interpreter.

But, normally you should use the `python3` command explicitly.

Comment: Yes. You are right. But I also tried "$ which pip" with no result, although I know there is a 'pip' command in /home/henrik/.local/bin/ - and that one must be used when I do this command: "~$ python3 -m pip install --upgrade --user pip setuptools virtualenv" - although it is not reported by 'which'... Because I get this warning: "WARNING: The scripts pip, pip3 and pip3.8 are installed in '/home/henrik/.local/bin' which is not on PATH." So I am still confused...!!

Comment: Maybe I should add, that if I do "which pip3" I get "/usr/bin/pip3".

Comment: You said " '/home/henrik/.local/bin' which is not on PATH." So any executable put there will not be found by the Shell or the `which` command. That's normal. Isn't it?

Comment: That sounds reasonable, but then why/how did the "~$ python3 -m pip install --upgrade --user pip setuptools virtualenv" command find it? I have just written another post about this, where you can see the whole Terminal output and the content of the different pip files here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1275327/why-are-there-diffferent-pip3-scripts-in-different-places-on-20-04

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. On Ubuntu 20.04 with two versions of python installed `python` seems to be defined. `which python` has no response, but `python` opens the python3.7 interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

If `which python` returns nothing but `python` still gives you a python shell, `python` might be defined as an alias (check with `alias python`).

Comment: This was exactly my problem. I forgot that I had added `alias python='python3'` in my `.bash_aliases` file.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no `python` executable. Instead, there is `python3`.

```
raj@jarek-02:~$ which python
raj@jarek-02:~$ python

Command 'python' not found, did you mean:

  command 'python3' from deb python3
  command 'python' from deb python-is-python3

    
raj@jarek-02:~$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `which` command, it is better to use the `bash` "builtin" named `type`. For more information see `help type`.

This command will also locate *aliases* and "*builtins*":

```
$ which python
$ type python
bash: type: python: not found
$ alias python=/usr/bin/python3
$ which python
$ type python
python is aliased to `/usr/bin/python3'
$ which type
$ type type
type is a shell builtin
$ which which
/usr/bin/which
$ type which
which is hashed (/usr/bin/which)
```